# Find syntax error in data visualization with python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I can't find any error in this syntax. Can you guys help me to find the error in this syntax? Thank You

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tabel = (pd.read_csv("https://storage.googleapis.com/dqlab-dataset/usia_karyawan.csv")
         .sort_values("Kelompok Usia", ascending=False)
         .set_index("Kelompok Usia")
        )
tabel["Laki-laki"] = -tabel["Laki-laki"]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(14, 6))
fig.suptitle("Perbandingan Jumlah Karyawan Laki-laki dan Perempuan\nBerdasarkan Kelompok Usia",
            x=0., y=1.0, fontsize=24, fontweight="bold", ha="left")
tabel["Laki-laki"].plot(kind="barh", ax=axes[0], color="tab:blue", xlim=[-550, 0])
tabel["Perempuan"].plot(kind="barh", ax=axes[1], color="tab:orange", fontsize=14, xlim[0, 550])
axes[0].set_ylabel("")
axes[0].tick_params(left=False, bottom=False, labelleft=False, labelbottom=False)
axes[0].legend(["Laki-laki"], fontsize=14, bbox_to_anchor=(0., 0., 1., .05))
axes[0].set_frame_on(False)
axes[1].set_ylabel("")
axes[1].tick_params(left=False, bottom=False, labelbottom=False)
axes[1].legend(["Perempuan"], fontsize=14, bbox_to_anchor=(0., 0., 0.3, .05))
axes[1].set_frame_on(False)
for i, m, w in zip(range(tabel.shape[0]), list(tabel["Laki-laki"]), list(tabel["Perempuan"])):
    axes[0].annotate(str(abs(m)), (m+20, i), xytext=(m+20, i),
                     color="w", va="center", ha="center", fontsize=14)
    axes[1].annotate(str(abs(w)), (w-20, i),xytext=(w-20, i),
                     color="w", va="center", ha="center", fontsize=14)
plt.tight_layout(rect=(0,0,1,0.88))
plt.show()
```

Error message:

```
tabel["Perempuan"].plot(kind="barh", ax=axes[1], color="tab:orange", fontsize=14, xlim[0, 550])
                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXWsp.png)

Comment: `xlim[0, 550]` is the syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Based on line above line with error, you are missing `=` after `xlim`:

```py
tabel["Perempuan"].plot(kind="barh", ax=axes[1], color="tab:orange", fontsize=14, xlim=[0, 550])
#                                                                     this is missing ^
```

The error tells you, that positional argument (argument without name) cannot go after keyword argument (argument with name)

Comment: @Dian Fadlu Rahman If this answer solved your problem, please, [mark this answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)